# Jquery sliding out/in box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem showing and hidden a text box.

You can see it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/CVPSg/

**Problem:**

I want to click `<li><a href="# " title=" ">About</a></li>`
and show the `<aside id="aboutBox">` coming from the left part of the screen (display: none)

Then, I want to close `<aside id="aboutBox">` with `<h2><a href="#" title=" ">Close X</a></h2>`

Also, The `<aside id="aboutBox">` does not hidden and/or does not move to the left once again to display none.

It keeps moving to the right of the screen.

I hope it makes sense.

And I have added the code here as well:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="extras">
          <li><a href="# " title=" ">About</a></li>
            <!-- <li>Blog</li> For the future -->
            <li class="hidesearch showsearch">
                <form action="http://www.racamstudio.com/searchSubmit" method="post" name="seachform">
                    <input type="text" id="searchInputRight" value="Search..." in-focus="false" name="searchText">
                    <input width="16" height="16" type="image" id="searchbuttonRight" alt="Submit" name="submit" src="http://www.racamstudio.com/resources/images/search_icon_over.gif">
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- end extras-->


        <aside id="aboutBox">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.</p>
            <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.</p>
            <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.</p>
              <h2><a href="#" title=" ">Close X</a></h2>
         </aside><!-- end aboutbox -->
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    // slideshow
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 340;
    var slides = $('#aboutBox');
    var numberOfSlides = 2; // slides.length: show all images 
    // Remove scrollbar in JS - It is added in CSS for user how does not have js enable
    $('#aboutBox').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div 
    // variable slides = #aboutBox
    slides.wrapAll('<div id="wrapAbout"></div>').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $('#wrapAbout').css('width', '340px');

    // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
    $('.extras li a').bind('click', function() {
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id') == 'left') ? currentPosition + 1 : currentPosition - 1;
        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#aboutBox').animate({
            'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition),
            'display': 'block'
        });
    });
    // manageControls: Hides and shows controls depending on currentPosition
    function manageControls(position) {
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if (position == 0) {
            $('#aboutBox').hide()
        } else {
            $('#aboutBox').show()
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to happen, and what's happening instead?

Comment: I want to click <li><a href="# " title=" ">About</a></li>
and show the <aside id="aboutBox"> Then. I want to close it with  <h2><a href="#" title=" ">Close X</a></h2>
Problem: The <aside id="aboutBox"> does not display none and/or does not move to the left and goes.

Comment: try to narrow down your problem, remove all the code that is not related to your prob and after post it here

Comment: I know that this is not what you want, but I can also see from your code that there's only half of the stuff there right now and everything is pretty much all over the place, so maybe this very stripped–down version will give you some clues: http://jsfiddle.net/CVPSg/1/

Comment: @polarblau - That is great man!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `overflow:hidden` on the slide-out, you want that on the wrapper. You don't want to animate the `margin-left` or `display`, you want to animate the wrapper's width. There's no need to absolutely position your slide-out either. Also, you can simplify things by handling the show and hide actions in separate handlers:

```
var slideWidth = 340;
var slides = $('#aboutBox').css('width', slideWidth);
slides.css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slides.attr('scrollHeight')
});
var wrapper = slides.wrap('<div>').parent().css({
    width: 1,
    height: slides.height(),
    overflow: 'hidden',
    display: 'none'
});
$('#show').click(function() {
    if(wrapper.is(':visible'))
        return;
    wrapper.show().animate({
        width: '+=' + slideWidth
    }, 'slow');
});
$('#hide').click(function() {
    wrapper.animate({
        width: 1
    }, 'slow', function() {
        wrapper.hide();
    });
});
```

I tweaked the HTML and CSS a bit too: I added `id` attributes to the show and hide links and dropped all the positioning for `#aboutBox`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mp7aR/

Comment: The code looks mucg more cleaner than mine but I is not really what I am looking for. However, it is almost there. I am looking for to archive something like this: jsfiddle.net/CVPSg/1

Comment: @Martin: polarblau's solution is a nice one, glad you got it sorted out. Shame that polarblau didn't post that as an answer.